# How do I do a leg sweep?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I have done a leg sweep a few times before, but it's usually by accident. I know that it's `RT` + `B` on xbox but I'm not sure what the other parameters are. Does it happen when I am locked onto an enemy? Do I have to have my hookblade equipped? Do I have to be running? `RT` + `B` also makes me do a hook-and-throw, a hook-and-run, and a grab when I'm in combat. What is the special circumstance that makes the leg sweep an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leg sweep civilians, which means that you don't need to be locked on in order to do it.  I can do it with my fists or my hookblade out, so that's not a factor either.

The hook-and-x moves require that you be moving in high profile towards someone hostile while you have no target, and depending on if you tap or hold the B button, you'll either hook and throw (tap) or hook and run (hold).

If you're not moving fast enough, or you have them targeted, you'll do a grab instead.

It seems to only give me the option to leg sweep if the person's not hostile, so a guard that doesn't have a red arrow above their head can be leg swept, but once you've done that, they go hostile and you'll do hook-and-x or grab moves instead.

The hook-and-x and leg sweep moves are more for escaping or avoiding being staggered when you hit someone, so you can't be in combat mode (ie, locked on) in order to do them.  Leg sweeping seems to be more focused on non-combatants, and hook-and-x for hostiles.

Once in combat, pressing the "high profile" button makes you block instead of run, so you're doing more close quarters moves with the B button.

Comment: Many guards just ate dirt and cobblestones to bring you this information :)

Comment: Thank you for doing this excellent (and highly important) research!